# WebPack RegEx Strip items from code like $log.debug

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack

I am attempting to use a regex match to strip all of the $log.debug from my codebase but it never seems to match. I verified that my regex is correct and matches exactly how I want it to match

The js looks like

...function(){}$log.debug("This is a message");function()... like thousands of statements like this and I just want to strip them all out... I tried the following two loaders with no joy.

I can get it to match on log or just plain text but when I use regex nothing seems to match. The documentation says that it supports it in the fashion I am using it.

```
{ test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'string-replace-loader',
        query: {
          multiple: [
             { search: '\$log.debug.*;', replace: '', flags: 'g'}
          ]
        }
      }


{ test: /\.js$/, loader: WebpackStrip.loader('$log.debug', 'console.log') }
```

Comment: Do you not need to escape the `.` in your regex pattern too? `'\$log\.debug.*;'`

Comment: That is correct but in this case the . matches any character I think and since there is a . there, it is a coincidence, but it technically should be escaped... That being said, neither way actually works with the loader. However, that works just fine in a plain JS test...

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, you need to escape the escape character for this to work because of the String object being passed to the RegEx in JS... I'm a novice at regex pretty much so I just make two statements to make sure I get all the $log.debug with or without the ; at the end of the line since there might be some that don't.

```
...
    multiple: [
                 { search: '\\$log.debug.*;', replace: '', flags: 'g'},
                 { search: '\\$log.debug.*\\)', replace: '', flags: 'g'}
...
```